# Does Bintray implement the artifactory api?

Tags: artifactory, spinnaker

I am working on a delivery pipeline within spinnaker.  Spinnaker has support for searching artifactory for artifacts and then triggering a pipeline.  I have been publishing my maven artifacts to bintray.com and assumed that this would work for triggering my pipelines.

I've configured spinnaker with this information...

```
hal config repository artifactory enable
hal config repository artifactory search add bintray \
           --base-url https://dl.bintray.com/$USERNAME \
           --repo maven-repo \
           --groupId $GROUP_ID \
           --username $USERNAME \
           --password $PASSWORD
```

However I getting errors in the igor service log saying...

```
2019-08-15 14:20:00.262  WARN 1 --- [RxIoScheduler-3] c.n.s.i.a.ArtifactoryBuildMonitor        : Unable to query Artifactory for artifacts (HTTP 405):
```

I'm wondering if I am falsely assuming that bintray implements the artifactory api.

Does bintray.com implement the artifactory api?

Answer (score 0):

Bintray's API isn't the same as Artifactory.
It has its own API, documented [here](https://bintray.com/docs/api/).